# Convert regex from Java to Go

Tags: java, regex, go

```
(?<=^|[a-z]\-|[\s\p{Punct}&&[^\-]])([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*-\d+)(?![^\W_])
```

I use the library reregexp2

This RE does not work in Go and will report error:

```
regexp2: Compile(`(?<=^|[a-z]\-|[\s\p{Punct}&&[^\-]])([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*-\d+)(?![^\W_])`): error parsing regexp: unknown unicode category, script, or property 'Punct' in `(?<=^|[a-z]\-|[\s\p{Punct}&&[^\-]])([A-Z][A-Z0-9_]*-\d+)(?![^\W_])`
```

I hope it can be executed normally

Comment: what is `\p{Punct}`? I think you get the error because of this part.

Comment: @AminRashidbeigi See https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Comment: @KonradRudolph yeah but I think `Punct` makes this error. It is not proper keyword. nah?

Comment: @Amin `Punct` is the name of a POSIX character class and [the Java regex engines seem to support the name using the Unicode class notation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class). But you're right, it's not officially defined. `\p{Punctuation}` should work.

Comment: For those wondering about `\p{Punct}`, that's from Java's `Pattern` class (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix)).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Punctuation is not valid, what it's valid is `\p{P}` but the problem is the punctuation from Java is not the same as Go so he'll need to map more characters. So if he want's to use `\p{P}` what he needs to do is to start the regex with `(?P<name>=^|[a-z]-|[\s\p{P}...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [`Java regex Pattern documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), you'll see that `\p{Punct}` is `Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~`

> \p{Punct}  Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

So what you need to convert this to a go regex checking the [`regexp syntax documentation`](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax)